# Creating Typescript Interface for Function that Accepts Other Functions as Parameters

Tags: typescript

I have a case where I am passing the resolve and reject Promise functions as delegates into another function:

```
//The function
someFunc(x, y, resolve, reject);
```

However I am not able to create my interface in a way that does not throw the following error:

```
Argument of type '(value?: {} | PromiseLike<{}>) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(reason?: any) => Promise<void>'.
```

Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Promise'.

My interface is currently as follows:

```
someFunc(prop1: string, prop2: string, callingFunctionResolve?: Promise<void>, callingFunctionReject?: Promise<void>);
```

I have also tried this but receive a different error:

```
callingFunctionResolve(reason: any)?: Promise<void>, callingFunctionReject(reason?: any)?: Promise<void>)

 A parameter initializer is only allowed in a function or constructor implementation.
```

Is there currently a way in Typescript to accomplish using delegates in this manner? I have seen things that suggest yet but have not come across anything that has worked or is this exact type of use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can check the [lib.es6.d.ts](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts) file to figure out the signature for the resolve/reject functions.
They are defined in the [PromiseConstructor](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/lib/lib.es6.d.ts#L5269):

```
interface PromiseConstructor {
    ...

    new <T>(executor: (resolve: (value?: T | PromiseLike<T>) => void, reject: (reason?: any) => void) => void): Promise<T>;

    ...
}
```

So your function should be:

```
function someFunc(
    prop1: string,
    prop2: string,
    callingFunctionResolve?: (value?: void | PromiseLike<void>) => void,
    callingFunctionReject?: (reason?: any) => void) { }
```

You can then:

```
new Promise<void>((resolve, reject) => {
    someFunc("str1", "str2", resolve, reject);
});
```

([code in playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=function%20someFunc(%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop1%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20prop2%3A%20string%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20callingFunctionResolve%3F%3A%20(value%3F%3A%20void%20%7C%20PromiseLike%3Cvoid%3E)%20%3D%3E%20void%2C%0D%0A%20%20%20%20callingFunctionReject%3F%3A%20(reason%3F%3A%20any)%20%3D%3E%20void)%20%7B%20%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Anew%20Promise%3Cvoid%3E((resolve%2C%20reject)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20someFunc(%22str1%22%2C%20%22str2%22%2C%20resolve%2C%20reject)%3B%0D%0A%7D)%3B))